# How to merge documents from two different indexes using Spring elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, jpa

I am new to elastic-search and i am trying to use spring data elastic search in the application. I have a requirement where in there are two separate indexes and i want to fetch documents from both indexes in one query based on some condition.

I would try to explain it with sample example with the same scenario.
There are two Different classes for individual indexes.

```
@Document(indexName = "Book", type = "Book")
public class Book {

@Id
private String id;

@Field(type = FieldType.String)
private String bookName;

@Field(type = FieldType.Integer)
private int price;

@Field(type = FieldType.String)
private String authorName;

//Getters and Setters

}
```

There is one more class Author

```
@Document(indexName = "Author", type = "Author")
public Class Author{

@Id
private String id;

@Field(type = FieldType.String)
private String authorName;

//Getters and setters
}
```

So there are two indexes one Book and Other Author.
I want to fetch all the documents where authorName in Book index is equal to authorName in Author index.
Can i get the details from both the index as a single document like merged result.
It would be very helpful if anyone can suggest solution for this usecase.

Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: what is your elasticsearch version ?

Comment: @LucE, the version 7.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. the document in the Author index is not the same document as the document in the Book index. they are two different documents. the closest thing I can think of is querying multiple indices with the same query -
just add multiple indices to the indexCoordinates.of method to search for the same filed\value in both indices.
for example:

```
elasticsearchTemplae.search(query, returnedObjectClass, indexCoordinates.of("Author", "Book")).
```

it will return all the search hits with both indices mentioned, which have to fulfill the query conditions, whichever they are.

Comment: I also created a dto and in the dto i construct the new object to return.

Comment: in elasticsearch you can't use join, so I would just use the "terms query", include both indices, aggregate the answer and tailor it to your needs. it's a bit complex, so if it's not a lot of data, I would find a simpler way to join/merge the objects, like your dto. but it can be done with aggregations: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/aggregation-across-multiple-indices/271350